# XPath: encode-for-uri() but keep characters allowed in IRIs unencoded

Tags: xpath, uri, urlencode, iri

XPath has the function `encode-for-uri()` that makes a string safe for use in a URI path segment:

```xml
encode-for-uri('AC/DC') => AC%2FDC
```

But it also %-encodes international characters:

```xml
encode-for-uri('汉/语') => %E6%B1%89%2F%E8%AF%AD
```

This is indeed necessary for URIs, but it is *not* necessary for IRIs, which are allowed to include these characters.

Is there a way to achieve the effect of `encode-for-uri()` in XPath while keeping i18n characters unencoded? Like this:

```xml
???('汉/语') => 汉%2F语
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `iri-to-uri()` function does what you are looking for.

However, it doesn't escape "/" - it's designed to operate on an entire IRI, not on a segment of the path.

Comment: AFAICT, `iri-to-uri()` encodes _exactly_ the characters that I _don't_ want encoded. (I edited the question to make it hopefully a bit clearer.)

Comment: OK, I see. Then I think the answer is no. (Or at any rate, you'll have to do it the hard way).